# Flow Redirection to SignIn or SignUp Based on Email Address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a scenario where I want to call technical profile of SignIn or SignUp based on Email Address.

Below are the code I implemented. It is working fine if Email Address present, it is calling SignIn profile but it is not working as expected for new email Address. For new email Address, it is throwing error as Account doesn't exist. I have included the "ContinueOnError" to skip the error but it is not working.

```
          <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccount-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadEmailAddress" ContinueOnError="true" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContinueOnError -Indicates whether validation of any subsequent validation technical profiles should continue if this validation technical profile raises an error. Possible values: true or false (default, processing of further validation profiles will stop and an error returned).
But as you have called only one validation technical profile and the email is not found for new user it returns an error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile#validationtechnicalprofiles